# Can you help me to explain this asm code?

Tags: assembly, x86

I have a piece of small code and I can't understand what it means. Can anyone help me to explain it?

```
mov     ecx, [esp+8]
mov     edx, [ecx]
inc     edx
mov     [ecx], edx
dec     edx
mov     al, [esp+4]
mov     [edx], al
mov     eax, [esp+4]
and     eax, 0FFh
retn
```

Comment: What don't you understand?

Comment: Why would anyone upvote this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(My assembly is a bit rusty, anyone please correct me if I'm wrong):

1. `esp` is the current stack-pointer, which is where locals and parameters typically live. `esp+8` would access an item that is 8 bytes offset from the current stack-frame address. The `[x]` denotes a dereferencing, so the local is a pointer type.
2. This value is copied into the `ecx` general-purpose register.
3. The value of `ecx` is then interpreted as a pointer and is dereferenced into `edx`, indicating it's a pointer-to-pointer type.
4. The value of `edx` is incremented (possibly pointing to the next element in an array with 1-byte sized elements).
5. The value of `edx` is copied back into the address that `ecx` is pointing at.
6. `edx` is then decremented.
7. The stack value at offset 4 is copied into the lower 8 bits of the `a` register (which is a different view of the `eax` and `ax` register).
8. This value is then copied into whereever `edx` is pointing to.
9. The same value from step 7 is re-used and ANDed with 0xFF - which is effectively the same thing as copying into `al` (as both only handles the lower 8 bits of the value).
10. Finally `retn` gets the return address from the stack and resumes execution from that address onward.

In C, I think this is a close approximation:

```
...
char* a = ... // local at offset +4
char** b = ... // local at offset +8
char* c = *b;
c++;
(*c)--;
*c = a; // lower 8-bits implicit if `sizeof(char) == 1` and 1 byte is 8 bits (non-octet systems do exist)
char* d = a & 0xFF;
return;
```

I'm not entirely sure what's going on here as it looks like you're missing instructions that came before what you posted.

Comment: You're like a walking manual. It would be interesting to automate this into some website like those regex explainers.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm sorry because missing instructions before posting. I won't do it again.

Comment: @simonzack I like that idea! wanna work on it together? :D